# Problem with xCode programming SQL Table

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, ios4, ios-frameworks

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' ('%@' TEXT PRIMARY KEY, '%@' TEXT);", tableName, field1, field2];
```

I faced quite a lot of problems with this line of programming, can anyone help me solve the problem? I'm new to Xcode. Thanks! :)

Comment: which kind of problems you are facing? Please mention what is happening with the line , error or crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the single quotes

```
SString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %@ (%@ TEXT PRIMARY KEY, %@ TEXT);", tableName, field1, field2];
```